# Prevent Dir deleting

Tags: java, file, file-io

the following code is deleting files and DIRS in a specific folder. 
How could I adjust it, so it will delete only the files in the folder but not the **dirs** inside

code:

```
            File folder = new File(path);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            if (listOfFiles != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
                {
                    logger.debug("File name=" + listOfFiles[i].toString() + " is Deleted!");
                    listOfFiles[i].delete();
                }
            }
```

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        if (listOfFiles != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++)
            {                    
                if( !listOfFiles[i].isDirectory() ){   // if not a directory...
                    logger.debug("File name=" + listOfFiles[i].toString() + " is Deleted!");
                    listOfFiles[i].delete();
                }
            }
        }
```

Make sense?  :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy ...

```
if (!listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
    listOfFiles[i].delete();
}
```

---

FWIW - your current code will only delete **empty** subdirectories. According to the javadoc, deleting a directory that is non-empty will fail; i.e. return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`File.isDirectory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29)

```
if(!listOfFiles[i].isDirectory())
{
    logger.debug("File name=" + listOfFiles[i].toString() + " is Deleted!");
    listOfFiles[i].delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory()

```
 if (!listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) { listOfFiles[i].delete(); }
```